# How to Get Started in Computer Science

Tags: software-engineering

I am wondering how to get started in studying theoretical computer science and how to apply it to my programming. I am fairly comfortable with basic programming, having been programming in mainly C++ but also Java for the past couple of years, so I don't necessarily need an introduction to programming.

What I am looking for to start is perhaps something fairly broad, so that it gives a wide overview of computer science, as I don't know exactly where I want to study within it yet. But it could also be nice to have directions of where to look to continue studying a specific aspect of it. However, this is just what I think could be helpful, and I am open to any recommendations.

Comment: I'm sorry for the downvotes. Perhaps the folks at [cseducators.se] would be more accommodating.

Comment: About the fact that it was put on hold, I realize the broadness and generality of the problem is not what Stack Overflow is necessarily for, so I may move this post over to Reddit sometime soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretical computer science means different things to different people. However, here are some areas which are commonly taught in undergraduate theoretical computer science classes:

- Combinatorics and elementary set theory. This serves as prerequisite to all that follows.
- Data structures and algorithms. One standard textbook is [Introduction to algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), but it might be too advanced if you're just starting out.
- Computability and automata theory. One standard textbook is *Introduction to the theory of computation* by Michael Sipser.

In some places, another core subject is functional programming and [labmda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

An undergraduate degree in computer science typically deals with several other topics, such as operating systems, networking, and sometimes compilation.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I'll be sure to check out all of those sources. I have heard good things about Introduction to Algorithms, so I'll take a look.